# Adding diagonal strikes and dotted rules to a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to format a table created in *OpenOffice Calc* using *HTML* / *CSS*. There are a few problems I'm running into, but one of the bigger ones is how do I add dotted guidelines inside the cell like this example?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use a `background-image` for all the `<td>`. Do you tried it?

Comment: @tomloprod exactly that is the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve the problem of the dotted guidelines:

---

#### METHOD #1: Using `background` property.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="50" height="50" align="center" background="http://www.htmliseasy.com/table_tutor/myback.gif">1</td>
      <td width="50" height="50" align="center" background="http://www.htmliseasy.com/table_tutor/myback.gif">2</td>
      <td width="50" height="50" align="center" background="http://www.htmliseasy.com/table_tutor/myback.gif">3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JSFiddle with `background` property of the cell: https://jsfiddle.net/qvoLLky9/2/

---

#### METHOD #2: Using CSS instead the `background` property of the cell:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
     <tr>
       <td width="50" height="50" align="center" class="guidelines">1</td>
       <td width="50" height="50" align="center" class="guidelines">2</td>
       <td width="50" height="50" align="center" class="guidelines">3</td>
     </tr>
</table>

.guidelines{
    background-image:url("http://www.htmliseasy.com/table_tutor/myback.gif");
}
```

JSFiddle with CSS `background-image` property: https://jsfiddle.net/qvoLLky9/3/

---

> **NOTE:** Replace my image (*myback.gif*) by yours (*guidelines*)

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughtful answer, I think this will work for me. Nice clear code for a beginner like myself. I only wish I had more reputation to vote your post up. (this is my first post on stackoverflow) Thanks!

Comment: @Bodhi1 Don't worry :) Welcome to StackOverflow.